# Facebook share button for Android not enabled, stays faded

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I am trying to add the Facebook share in Android.
I have added the button in xml like this

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
            android:id="@+id/ivShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

In java I have tried to implement it like this

```
@OnClick(R.id.ivShare)
public void onShareClick() {

    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello There")
            .setContentDescription(
                    "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()))
            .build();

    shareButton.setShareContent(linkContent);
    shareButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Timber.d("share result %s", result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

But the only thing that I get is this faded, unclickable share button. I have also made an app on developers.facebook.com, added a release key hash and made the app live there.
[image]

Comment: I think there is a problem with ``.setContentURL`` check if the URL works. Also see if this helps http://scottwestover.blogspot.com/2015/07/android-adding-facebook-share-button.html

Comment: No, the URL is fine and I have checked the blog and still can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having a similar issue.